# Is it possible to reconstruct a puppeteer Response object from its JSON?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, puppeteer

If I have a stringified version of a puppeteer Response object, is it possible to recreate the actual object?

The Response constructor is pretty straightforward:

```
constructor(client, request, status, headers, fromDiskCache, fromServiceWorker, securityDetails) {
```

However, in order to recreate that object, it looks like I also need to recreate its Request object (`request` in the Response constructor above).  That's where I'm having problems.  The Request constructor takes a `payload` parameter, but that information doesn't appear in the stringified version of a Response (unless I'm missing something).

Here's the Request constructor:

```
constructor(client, requestId, interceptionId, isNavigationRequest, allowInterception, url, resourceType, payload, frame, redirectChain) {
```

Does anyone know how to find this payload information, to recreate the Request object?

Alternatively, is there a better way to recreate a Response object from the JSON that I'm completely overlooking?

Comment: If you came up with a different solution please, let us know... if it helped you, please accept my answer. Both could be really useful for other users looking for the same (or a similar) answer 

Answer (score 0):

You can get the request payload by intercepting every request and copying the request payload

```
page.on('request', request => {
  request.postData(); // that's what you need
  request.continue(); // don't forget to allow the request to go ahead
});
```